# returns attribute undefined in jquery

Tags: jquery, undefined

html

```
<span class="checkbox" GroupName="ckmill">
<input id="ctl01" type="checkbox" name="ctl01" />
<label for="ctl01">A</label></span>
```

js

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.checkbox').click(function(){
            var  $text2=$(this);

            alert($text2.attr("text"));
        });
    });​
```

while executing it shows.. `UNDEFINED`

What is the solution?

Comment: What do you expect it to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Dmeo**: http://jsfiddle.net/LuRqK/

2 things:

1) to get the attribute of the inner input use `children` http://api.jquery.com/children/

2) to get the text or html use `.text` or `.html` api

**codE**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.checkbox').click(function(){
            var  $text2=$(this);
             alert($text2.text());
            alert($text2.children('#ctl01').attr('name'));
        });
    });​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text content of the span:

```
alert($text2.text());
```

There is no "text" attribute to use as a selector. If you want the HTML content of the span, use:

```
alert($text2.html());
```

Answer (score 0):

text is not an attribute of an HTML tag, you have to use `$text2.text()`.

Attributes are things defined inside of the tag, like `href` in an anchor tag (`<a href="website.com"></a>`) or `id` in almost any tag (`<div id="hello">Text</div>`).

To get the text inside of the div with the attribute `id` being `hello` (which is "Text"), then you have to use `.text()`.

```
alert($text2.text());
```

or to get the HTML content

```
alert($text2.html());
```

Answer (score 0):

The object doesn't seem to have any attribute "text".
you should use

```
alert($text2.html());
```

or

```
alert($text2.text());
```